# How do you execute a method from a different Project within the same Solution?

Tags: c#, projects-and-solutions

I have two c# projects within one solution. Within one project (Project1), I have some code that runs when a user clicks on the button (public void btnTranslate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e).

what I want to do is when a user clicks on a button in the other project (Project2), that it will run the code found in Project1 (public void btnTranslate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e).

I have added the reference (Project 1) to the code behind in Project2, so I have the code:

using Project1; in the file.

Thanks!

Comment: Create the class the method belongs to and then call the method on the instance of the class you just created. But your method isn't just any method its an Event from a UI. So  it presumably has sideeffects or won't even work when that form isn't shown. When showing the form was your intention in the first place that might be ok (somewhat) but if not you are definetly going the wrong route.

Comment: Try UserControl project for such behaviour and add that UserControl reference in both projects